# MySQL Stored Procedure anonymous

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySql and I have an requirement that is:

I am passing 5 parameters to a procedure and based 5 parameters values I am building a dynamic query. After that I am converting this dynamic query into prepared statement using mysql prepare statement, after finishing prepare statement I am executing prepare statement like this

EX: `execute stmt using @param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,@param5`

Now my question is

How can I pass these five parameters `(@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,@param5)` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the values in as parameters to the procedure, then assign to user variables for statement execution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo(p1 INT, p2 INT, p3 INT, p4 INT, p5 INT) BEGIN
  PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?';
  SET @param1 := p1, @param2 := p2, @param3 := p3, @param4 := p4, @param5 := p5;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```